# Hibernate not throwing any error nor saving the record in database when used with ExecutorService

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java.util.concurrent

Why is JPARepository.save method not working when used inside an ExecutorService task?

```
@Component
public class Testing {
@Inject
JobSummaryRepository jobSummaryRepository;
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobSummary.class);

@PostConstruct
public void Save(){
    JobSummary js = new JobSummary();
    js.setCount(1L);
    js.setCity_id(1L);
    js.setCompany_id(1L);
    js.setDate(new Date());
    js.setJob_master_id(1L);
    js.setHub_id(1L);
    js.setUser_id(1L);
    js.setJob_status_id(1L);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(this.CallablecustomSaveOrUpdate(js));
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        log.info("What!!");
    }
    //jobSummaryRepository.save(js);
    executor.shutdown();
}
private Callable<String> CallablecustomSaveOrUpdate(JobSummary js){
    return () -> {
        jobSummaryRepository.save(js);
        return "Done";
    };
}
```

}

The code above doesn't throw any error nor saves any data in the database. Finally block is not executed as well.

On the other hand, commenting out ExecutorService logic and calling jobSummaryRepository.save(js) directly works perfectly fine.

I can't get my head around this.

Comment: Have you used debugger to check what is happening? Also how do you check that record exists or not in database? Have you configured transaction manager for your repository?

Comment: Yeah... Debugger just stops after the save statement. Doesn't do anything. No records in database saved. Code execution never reaches finally block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `@PostConstruct` is causing the problem. As it is called before all the spring component/context gets loaded.
You can use spring's [ContextRefreshedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) for this purpose.

Simple Example :

```
@Component
public Test implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
@Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
   //do something if all apps have initialised
  }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Cool. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try putting your `jobSummaryRepository.save(js)` in a Runnable, and pass an instance of this runnable to the executor service instead and see if that works

example Runnable :

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private JobSummary js;
    private JobSummaryRepository jobSummaryRepository;

    public MyRunnable(JobSummary js, JobSummaryRepository jsp) {
        this.js = js;
        this.jobSummaryRepository = jsp;
    }

    public void run() {
        js.setCount(1L);
        js.setCity_id(1L);
        js.setCompany_id(1L);
        js.setDate(new Date());
        js.setJob_master_id(1L);
        js.setHub_id(1L);
        js.setUser_id(1L);
        js.setJob_status_id(1L);
        jobSummaryRepository.save(js);
    }
}
```

Then your Testing class could look like below

```
public class Testing {

    public void testSave() {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Future future = executor.submit(new MyRunnable(new JobSummary(), new JobSummaryRepository()));
        try {
            future.get();
        }
        ...
        ...
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if it works, I would like to know the reason behind this behavior. I learned Future in java today and wanted to use it in my code, But for some reason, this isn't working.

I need to know why.

Comment: you would still use Future, but instead of Callable you could pass an instance of a Runnable eg : `Future future = executor.submit(new YourClassImplementingRunnable(js));`
On a side note, you should improve your methods naming convention. These should start with lowercase letters : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions

Comment: This is not production code. I just replicated the issue in a simple class.